# Facebook Graph API for iPhone Error

Tags: ios4

can any one suggest what is API error code 1 in Graph API for Facebook
please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai all
In facebook, wall posts should be less than 420 characters.